# How to return values from functions into other functions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, palindrome

I'm trying check if a number is a palindrome in Javascript

I've converted a number to a string, and reversed it and saved it as a new variable: reverseNum. However, when I go to check if `num == reverseNum`, i can't seem to get the logic to work properly

```js
function palindrome() {
    function reverse(num) {
        num = num.toString();
        let reverseNum = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
            reverseNum.push(num[num.length - i]);

        }
        return reverseNum.join('');
    }

    function check(num, reverseNum) {
        //is palindrome
        if (num == reverseNum) {
            return true;
            //is not palindrome
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

console.log(palindrome(121));
```

expected output should be true if for example input: 121, output: 121

expected output should be false if for example input: 79, output: 97

Comment: You have `check` and `reverse` defined within `palindrome`, but you never call either of them anywhere.

Comment: Also, `palindrome()` doesn't seem to take any arguments.

Comment: And `palindrome` does not `return` anything either.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I tried adding the arguments num and reverseNum, but got an error so I took them out

Comment: Your code is unnecessary complicated try this 
`function test (val) {
 const newVal = val.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
 return val.toString() === newVal
}

console.log(121)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, this really just boils down to not passing a value into the function `palindrome` and then not returning anything from it. As such this is quite a quick fix:

```js
function palindrome(number) {
    function reverse(num) {
        num = num.toString();
        let reverseNum = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
            reverseNum.push(num[num.length - i]);

        }
        return reverseNum.join('');
    }

    function check(num, reverseNum) {
        //is palindrome
        if (num == reverseNum) {
            return true;
            //is not palindrome
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return check(number, reverse(number))
}

console.log(palindrome(1211));
```

This can be done with a little less code, by converting the number to an array, reversing, and then checking it:

```js
const palindrome = number => `${number}` === `${number}`
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('')

console.log(palindrome(121))
console.log(palindrome(1211))
```

---

**Edit**
To explain further, as requested.

I did think about converting this to standard functions in order to try and make it a little clearer, but I think it would be better to explain what's going on.

`${number}` just converts our number to a string. We want to do that so that we can more easily convert it to an array.

We want to convert it to an array because arrays have a `reverse` method, which is just what we need. So, in order to get a reversed array, we can use:

```
`${number}`
    .split('')
    .reverse()
```

So now we have an array which is the characters of our number reversed. We now need to get that into a form which we can use to compare to the original number. To do that, we can get it back to a string using `join()`. Now we have a reversed string of the initial number. Now, we just need to compare that to the initial number to see if we have a palindrome.

As it's not really ideal to compare a number to a string, we need to convert one of them. In my example, I've converted the initial number to a string using `${number}`.

The arrow syntax is just shorthand for a standard function (though there are some other differences which are not relevant for now).

Because the methods we use take in an array, and return an array, we can chain them together to make the code nice and simple.

In summary:

```
// convert our numbers to strings
`${number}` === `${number}`

    // split the string into an array
    .split('')

    // reverse the array
    .reverse()

    // convert the array back to a string
    .join('')
```

If you have any specific questions, just let me know!

Comment: Could you explain the first line a little bit more?

Comment: The first line of the second example?

Comment: @OliverRadini, if you use `function` it would be easier to parse for a beginner.

Comment: sure, I'll add a little explanation

Comment: @TylerMorales That's updated now with further explanation

Answer (score 1):

I created separate functions. Hopefully this helps.

```js
function reverse(num) {
    num = num.toString();
    var reverseNum = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
        reverseNum.push(num[num.length - i]);

    }
    return reverseNum.join('');
}

function palindrome(num) {
 var reverseNum = parseInt(reverse(num));

 console.log("Num:", num);
 console.log("Reverse Num:", reverseNum);
 
 if (num === reverseNum)
  return true;
    //is not palindrome
 else
  return false;
}

console.log(palindrome(121));
```

Comment: @Tyler Morales - if this answered your question, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two functions for this. Just a single function `palindrome()` is sufficient to check for palindromes.

1. Convert the parameter `num` into a string.
2. Assign `numString` to an empty string.
3. Push every character of the `num` string to the `numString` string.
4. Check if the new string `numString` is the same as the initial `num` string.

```js
function palindrome(num) {
  num = num.toString();
  let reverseNum = "";
  for(i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
    reverseNum += num.charAt(num.length - i);
  }  
  
  if (num == reverseNum) {
    console.log(num + " is a Palindrome!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log(num + " is not a Palindrome!!");
    return false;
  }
  
}

palindrome(224);
palindrome(424);
palindrome(222);
palindrome(363);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
function palindrome(num) {


        num = num.toString();
        let reverseNum = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
            reverseNum.push(num[num.length - i]);

        }
        var e=reverseNum.join('')
        alert(e)
        return check(num,e);

    }

    function check(num, reverseNum) {

        //is palindrome
        if (num == reverseNum) {
            return true;
            //is not palindrome
        } else {
            return false;
        }

}

alert(palindrome(121));
```

You didn't return the check function and there is error with your function scopes.